# After jQuery .load() function, jQuery sortable() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

After jQuery `.load()` function, jQuery `sortable()` doesn't work.

The same issue happened with jQuery on click event. I solved it with `$(document).on('click','selector',function(){})` instead of `$('selector',function(){})`.

But this time I could not do the same way.

What should I do? My sortable code block is this:

```
$(function () {
    $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(this.id)
            console.log(ui.item[0].id)

            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.origin + "/durumupdate/",
                data: {
                    colon_id: this.id + "",
                    card_id: ui.item[0].id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (response) { console.log(response) }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(this.id)
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `.load` in the code you posted but feels like you're replacing the `.droptrue` element in the `.load` callback.

If so, even though there is a `.droptrue` element, it's not **the same one you called `.sortable` for** on page load, this why it's not working.

The solution is to call `.sortable(...` in the `.load` callback. Assuming you call `.load` when a button `#myButton` has been clicked it should look something like:

```html
<div id="sortable-list">
  <ul class="droptrue">
    <li ....
  </ul>
</div>
```

```js
function makeSortable() {
  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
    ......
  });
}

$(function() {
  makeSortable();

  $('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#sortable-list').load('https://example.com #sortable-list', function() {
      makeSortable();
    });
  });
});
```